# jQuery - Find a word within a span and take that word and add the class to the span element

Tags: jquery, html, contains, addclass

I need help. I have been assigned the task of grabbing a word out of a span element, and then assigning that word to the same span element as a class.

I have written this piece of code:

```
jQuery(".product span").each(function() {
if(jQuery("this:contains('hat')")) {
    jQuery(this).addClass("hat");
} else if (jQuery("this:contains('sunglasses')")) {
    jQuery(this).addClass("sunglasses");
} else {
    jQuery(this).addClass("vest");
};  
});
```

It does not work as it should however. It assigns the class 'hat' to all of the span elements within the class 'products'.

When using this:

```
jQuery(".product span").each(function() {
if(jQuery("this:contains('hat')")) {
    jQuery(this).addClass("hat");
    };
});
```

It works and assigns the class of 'hat' to the same span element. It also works if I do it this way. But I would prefer not to have three lines of code like this:

```
jQuery(".product span:contains('hat')").addClass("hat");
```

I want it in a nice if and else statement or another way that uses parsing if possible.

**Other Note:** I am not using jQuery's shortcut because it will collide with other library's I amusing. I also know of the var $js = jQuery.noConflict(); method.

**A BIG BIG thanks to Sushanth, Kevin and Karl for the great response! I wish I could put both answers as the solution**

Comment: isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: No, I wanted a nice if and else statement that works.

Comment: :contains() is case-sensitive. Could this be your problem?

Comment: Also, because of the way your code is structured, if a span contains hat and sunglasses, only the class 'hat' will be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some mistake in your code.

`'this:contains("hat")'` will not work, it will search for a tagname called `this` and see if it contain 'hat'.

also, if you want to check if element exist, you need to check is length. `$('ANYThING')` will always be true.

I suggest to do this :

```
jQuery(".product span").each(function() {
    var $this = jQuery(this); //Caching this is optimal and less writing;
    if($this.is(":contains('hat')")) {
        jQuery(this).addClass("hat");
    } else if ($this.is(":contains('sunglasses')")) {
        $this.addClass("sunglasses");
    } else {
        $this.addClass("vest");
    };  
});
```

jQuery `.is()` doc : http://api.jquery.com/is/

Also, `:contains()` is case sensitive, so if you text is 'Sunglass' it will not work.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This was the solution to my problem! I was close. I never knew about .is(). I have learnt something new. Thanks again Karl!

Case sensitivity will be something I will need to think about in the future!

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery("this:contains('hat')")
```

supposed to be

```
jQuery(this).filter(":contains('hat')")
```

`this` when inside the quotes does not correspond to element or context. It is supposed to be used without the quotes

`jQuery(this)` and not `jQuery("this")`

**JS**

```
jQuery(".product span").each(function() {
   // cache the jQuery object
   var $this = jQuery(this);
   // check the length if it returns anything
   if($this.filter(":contains('hat')").length) {
       $this.addClass("hat");
   } else if ($this.filter(":contains('sunglasses')").length) {
       $this.addClass("sunglasses");
   } else {
      $this.addClass("vest");
   }  
});
```

[**Check Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/fQg28/1/)

Comment: `$this.filter(":contains('hat')")` is always true, you need to check the length.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. This method did not work when I added the extra code and double checked I had typed it all right. It still assigned the class 'electric' to all .product spans.

Comment: @patorikkuv2 It works in the fiddle, what differs in your code from the fiddle?

Comment: My bad, I missed the .length because I over looked the fiddle link :P. Thanks as well. Both methods are the solution. You guys are awesome! Thanks Kevin and Sushanth

Comment: @patorikkuv2.. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, very simply using the javascript [String replace function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Example%3a_Using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters)

Here's a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/wHBrP/5/) and the code below.

I also took the liberty, to rewrite the code, to make it a bit more readable

```
// Create a closure, where $ is assigned to jQuery, so we dont have to write it
(function ($) {

  $(".product span").each(function() {
    findClass(this,"hat");
    findClass(this,"sunglasses");
  });

  function findClass(el, word) {
    var $el = $(el); //cache element

    $el.text().replace(word, function (match) {
      $el.addClass(match); //add the class to our element
      return match; //return the same word, so it's not replaced
    });
  }

})(window.jQuery);
```

The `replace` function, takes two parameters, First is a string or [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) we are matching, second is a callback function, which returns a string to replace the match which we can use to our advantage

By using a RegExp, you also get the benefit of ignoring case. Simply replace

`"hat"` with `/hat/i` and you are done! (The `i` after the `/`, indicates ignore case)

Hope it helps

Comment: Ah, this is also a very awesome solution. Thanks Dogoku!